# GRU (gated recurrent unit) not working on GPU (TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train RNN models on my GPU (NVIDIA RTX3080) using TensorFlow, however GRU cells are not working properly.

When training LSTM models, it works fine and it takes only few seconds.

### Example

```
act = "tanh"
recurrent_act = "sigmoid"

lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, activation=act, recurrent_activation=recurrent_act),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, activation=act, recurrent_activation=recurrent_act),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

history = compile_and_fit(lstm_model, wide_window_d) 

# Epoch 1/120
# 368/368 [==============================] - 12s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2664 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2883 - val_loss: 0.0273 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0845
# Epoch 2/120
# 368/368 [==============================] - 5s 14ms/step - loss: 0.0067 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0381 - val_loss: 0.0063 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0435
```

However, when I use GRU cells, training takes 10x more time.

```
gru_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True, activation=act, recurrent_activation=recurrent_act),
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True, activation=act, recurrent_activation=recurrent_act),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

history = compile_and_fit(gru_model, wide_window_d)

# Epoch 1/120
# 368/368 [==============================] - 49s 129ms/step - loss: 0.1086 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1560 - val_loss: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0498
# Epoch 2/120
# 368/368 [==============================] - 48s 130ms/step - loss: 0.0018 - # mean_absolute_error: 0.0210 - val_loss: 0.0038 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0320
```

But the biggest problem is when I use Bidirectional GRU, because training time increases until it gets stuck and I have to restart kernel.

```
gru_model_bidirectional = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

history = compile_and_fit(gru_model_bidirectional, wide_window_d)

# Epoch 1/120
#  33/368 [=>............................] - ETA: 1:19 - loss: 0.5314 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4526
!! It always gets stuck at this point. Few seconds after start and I have to restart kernel.!!
```

### My specs and versions right now

I am using anaconda.

- Tensorflow: 2.4.1
- cudatoolkit: 11.2.1
- cudnn: 8.1.0.77
- Python: 3.8

### I have tried so far

I have tried to install various versions of tensorflow (even tf-nightly) and also other versions on cuda and cudnn, but I get stuck on Bidirectional GRU everytime.

I have also red that there might be some problem with GPUs memory that is why I added this to my code (after tensorflow import)

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

The problem with some older versions was that they do not support RTX30xx series cards.

#### Note

On cpu it also works fine (all those models above), however with larger models training takes too long on CPU.

So, if anyone knows why LSTM cells work totally fine (even bidirectional) and GRU cells are problematic please let me know. Thank you very much.

#### EDIT 1

Whole code

I have this class to work with models

```
class MyModel():
    
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        
    def load_model(self, dir_name):
        self.model = load_model(dir_name)
    
    def eval_mod(self, window, verbose):
        res = self.model.evaluate(window, verbose=verbose)
        print("Loss:", res[0], "MAE:", res[1])
        
    def save_model(self, name):
        self.model.save("models\\models_05_04_2021\\"+ name +".model")
        
    def retrain_model(self, window, patience, epochs):
        early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patience, mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)
        history = self.model.fit(window.train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=window.val, callbacks=[early_stopping])
        self.history = history
        
    def compile_and_fit(self, window, patience=3, epochs=120):

        ## callbacks list https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks
        early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                        patience=patience,
                                                        mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)
        
        # https://github.com/Jaewan-Yun/optimizer-visualization
        # https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model
        opt = tf.optimizers.Adam()
        self.model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                    optimizer=opt,
                    metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

        history = self.model.fit(window.train, epochs=epochs,
                          validation_data=window.val,
                          callbacks=[early_stopping])
        return history
```

Then training

```
act = "tanh"
recurrent_act = "sigmoid"

lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, activation=act, recurrent_activation=recurrent_act),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=act),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

lstm = MyModel(lstm_model)

history = lstm.compile_and_fit(wide_window_d)
```

Window is created using WindowGenerator class from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

```
wide_window_my = WindowGenerator(
    input_width=24, label_width=24, shift=FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT,train_df = train_df_my,val_df = val_df_my, test_df = test_df_my,label_columns=['to_predict'])
```

Comment: Maybe try the second variant? (i.e. the implementation of the original GRU). As mentioned in the docs:

"The second variant is compatible with CuDNNGRU (GPU-only) and allows inference on CPU. Thus it has separate biases for kernel and recurrent_kernel. To use this variant, set `reset_after=True` and `recurrent_activation='sigmoid''`"

Comment: @AmirMousavi. When GRU is defined like this: tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True)  those two parameters should already be reset_after=True and recurrent_activation='sigmoid' as they are default arguments. Or am I wrong? Btw thanks for help :)

Comment: Oh yep you're right, I thought the default behaviour would also be reflected in the default arguments.

I see you're trying to use V1, perhaps give this a try:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNGRU

Comment: So I tried using tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.GRU, but there is the same error. I think there will be some problem with cuda support for GRU cell, because I dont know why it would work on LSTM just fine and not with GRU.

Comment: @0ndre_, Did you tried with TF 2.4, CUDA 11.0 and cuDNN 8.0 ?

Comment: @TFer2 not those exact versions. I am gonna try it!

Comment: I have tried cuda 11.0 with tf 2.4.0 and version cudnn 8.0.4.30, 8.1.1.33 and 8.0.1.13 and GRU still not working.

Comment: @0ndre_, Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 I added my code. If you want the whole code I can send it to you, becuase It would be too long to write it here. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updating Tensorflow to `version > 2.5.0` solved the issue.